# Host 2 Magento websites on single instance in aws

Tags: aws, hosting, widget-instance

How can I deploy my second Magento website on and instance in which already one is running

in AWS

Answer (score 0):

probably the same way you installed your first magento?

create folder.

duplicate vhost in your webserver config and change domain name and root folder.

create database.

point DNS records to your servers IP address

easy.